# Assigning a Parent object to a Child object Without casting in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I have a parent interface and a child interface which objects will implement. I've made a child interface because I want a specific VehicleEntity object say `Truck` to add itself to the HashMap in `Car`. A `Truck` will call VehicleManager's `addToCar()` method which add the Truck object into Car's hashMap. The issue I have is `CarEntity ce = ve;`. Netbeans is telling me to cast `ve` to CarEntity but I don't want to. Shouldn't the line of code be valid (assuming the the object the for loop is looking at is a Car object)? How can I fix this?

```
public interface VehicleEntity {
    getId();
    getSpeed();
    move();
    }

public interface CarEntity extends VehicleEntity{
    addToCar(String c);
}

public class Car implements CarEntity{
HashMap<String, VehicleEntity> cars = new HashMap<String, VehicleEntity>();

    public void addToCar(String c) {
       cars.add(c);
    }
}

public class VehicleManager {
    HashMap<String, VehicleEntity> vehicles = new HashMap<String, VehicleEntity>();

public void reportToCar(String id) {
    for (VehicleEntity ve : ve.values()) {
        if (ve.getId().equals(id)) {
            CarEntity ce = ve; // Issue here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What class does that `reportToCar` method belong to?

Comment: There's more problems here... In `addToCar` you call `add` on a HashMap. There's no such method. You'll need to use `put(String c, Something s)`. What's that Something?

Comment: Yea, at first I had ArrayList, I forgot to change it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really, that's not at all valid.  You can move from the specific to the general without casting, but not back again.  For instance, you can store an ArrayList in a List variable, but you can't take a List and put it into an ArrayList variable without casting.  In the same way, you can't take a vehicle and say it is a car without explicitly casting.

So, in this case, since you know the vehicle is a car, cast to a car explicitly.

Comment: I see. That's what I thought at first, just needed some confirmation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what it is you're trying to reach here, so I'm gonna list some corrected classes with my best guesses first...

```
public interface VehicleEntity {

    public String getId();

    public String getSpeed();

    public void move();

}
```

---

```
public interface CarEntity extends VehicleEntity {

    public void addToCar(String key, CarEntity c);

}
```

---

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Car implements CarEntity{ 
HashMap<String, VehicleEntity> cars = new HashMap<String, VehicleEntity>();

    @Override
    public void addToCar(String key, CarEntity car) {
       cars.put(key, this);
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpeed() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void move() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

---

... then show you a cool trick using generics:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class VehicleManager {

    HashMap<String, VehicleEntity> vehicles =
        new HashMap<String, VehicleEntity>();

    public <T extends VehicleEntity> T report(String id) {
        for(VehicleEntity ve : vehicles.values()) {
            if(ve.getId().equals(id)) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                T ce = (T)ve;
                return ce;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void test() {

        final Car c = report("test");

    }

}
```

I've parameterized the method `report` with a `T` extending `VehicleEntity`. It will return something of that type `T`. When using this in method `test()`, we've stated that we want a `Car`. Now some type inference is gonna go on, automatically calling method `report` for the type `Car`. If the `VehicleEntity` in the map with the given id isn't a `Car`, we'll get a ClassCastException since we're trying to cast to `Car` when calling thet method in that context.

Comment: My problem was concerning casting. I do not want to cast but as @Micah stated it can't be done.

Comment: @Dan Sometimes you just have to cast. But I'm not certain what exactly your design is trying to achieve, so maybe a different approach would yield a different result. Without casts. Just not in your current structure. If you could have a separate VehicleManager for each type it could be avoided (with generics), but since that isn't the case, my suggestion could avoid having a separate method for each subtype of VehicleEntity you make. Something to keep in mind.